# Inbound mail doesn't work after deployment to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to parse inbound mail to my app by following the JavaMail-example in the GAE-docs.

It works great on the local debug-server, but does not after I deploy it to GAE.

The log in GAE reads:

> #
>      1.
>         11-10 04:41PM 34.887 /_ah/mail/testing@myappid.appspotmail.com 403 7ms 23cpu_ms 0kb
>          - - [10/Nov/2010:16:41:34 -0800] "POST /_ah/mail/testing@myappid.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 403 234 - - "myappid.appspot.com" ms=7 cpu_ms=23 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.001041

where "myappid" is obivously my correct app-id. So it seems to run into a 403 error, which is weird? I haven't set up any IP or other security restrictions. I am below my quota in all areas.

My web.xml-mapping is as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.myapp.server.inboundmail.MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(where, again, mycompany and myapp are the correct values)

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching off the SSL transport-requirement...